# Can you "use" middleware multiple times from different modules?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a module implementing a service that is using some middleware that it needs to do some processing, e.g.

```
module.exports = function(options) {
    ...
    app.use(busboy())
    ...
    return module
}
```

If I have another module that needs to use the same middleware, it is going to make the same call.  Each module is a plug-in and doesn't know about any of the others, and it doesn't seem like good design to create a global variable for each piece of middleware that a plug-in might use.  And per the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304234/check-if-a-given-middleware-is-being-used), it doesn't seem like a simple matter of checking if the middleware is already loaded.

Right now, no piece of middleware is used in more than one place, but if in the future it does, is this going to cause a problem?  If so, what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use particular middleware for particular routers/routes, include it for just those routers/routes, instead of application-wide.

So instead of this:

```
app.use(middleware);
```

You can use this:

```
let router = express.Router();

router.use(middleware);
router.get('/', ...);

// and return/export the router
```

Using [routers](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router) also makes your app more modular.

Comment: when I make this change, the route in question no longer appears to exist... is there something else I need to add?

Comment: @Michael that entirely depends on how your app/routes are structured.

Comment: ok, so I have some other calls to app.get, app.use, and app.post which come before and after this particular module.  When I use an URL that should match this particular route it now falls through to my catch all at the end.  how can i troubleshoot why it no longer handles the request using this particular route?

Comment: the linked documentation on routers shows an example where it is still necessary to call app.use to link the router into the app...

Comment: Yes, but instead of mounting the middleware, you mount the router (which it itself will mount the middleware). Routers (and route handlers) are _also_ middleware.

Comment: ah ok.  i had to try several things, but it appears that I just needed `app.use(router)`.