# NodeJs and ExpressJs middleware that relies on another middleware being used

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I am creating an express middleware. My index.js exports is a function that returns a function(req,res,next) {...}

```
function myMiddleware (options) {
    //some stuff with options...
    return function middleware(req, res, next) {
        //stuff
    }
}

module.exports = myMiddleware;
```

So the user would could start using my middleware like this:

```
var express = require('express'),
    myMiddleware = require('my-middleware'),

    app = express();
    app.use(myMiddleware());
```

The important thing is that I must make sure that middleware has access to cookies. Of course I could parse **req.header.cookie** myself but there exists a cookie-parser module that does the parsing for me.

So I would like to make sure that cookie-parser middleware is already being used when my middleware starts up. I could probably instruct the user to first use cookieParser() but I dislike it.

Is there a way to do it easily?

EDIT

I could even port cookie-parser since it is not a huge module. But that is probably the least thing I would do since it can introduce a lot of maintenance work that I would normally not do.

Comment: Look how krakenJS does it, you can declare priority levels in config to ensure the order of your middlewares. https://github.com/krakenjs/kraken-js/blob/v2.x/config/config.json

Comment: I think you could return a [composed middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/composable-middleware)

Comment: @DevDig hmmm this looks cool. I will sure try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

Force the `cookie-parser` middleware if `req.cookies` is undefined.
If `cookie-parser` has already been called, this call will be ignored. See: https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser/blob/master/index.js

The downfall to this approach is that the cookieParser middleware will only have the default options.

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

function myMiddleware(options) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    return cookieParser()(req, res, function() {
      // Your middleware code
      return next();
    });
  }
}
```

Give a warning if `req.cookies` is undefined

```
function myMiddleware(options) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    if(!req.cookies) {
      // Some warning
    }
    // Your middleware code
    return next();
  }
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted. But it was  easier to port code from cookie parser to my middleware. Now I will have a service that will parse cookies... I have subscribed to get notifications whenever something major happens on cookie-parser project... So I will try to keep full behavior of cookie parser - not only basic

Answer (score 2):

In express, the execution order of middleware is defined by the order it has been attached to the app/router.

`req.param` being an exception, as it is executed before any route handler that matches the parameter.

The order in which your routes and middleware functions are declared is the order which they will be executed. I do not know of a way to change this, maybe fiddling with the internals of express router, but there is no documented/clean way to achive this by default.

To make sure your middleware has access to the cookie parsed by `cookie-parser`, attach the cookie parsing middleware **before** any route definitions.

```
        app.use(cookieParser());
        // all other middleware that uses cookies
```

Comment: good answer, source : https://derickbailey.com/2016/05/09/in-what-order-does-my-express-js-middleware-execute/

Comment: Actually this is not the answer to my question. I of course know this. But I am creating an external module that will be served via npm. And I cannot know whether the programmer that will try to use my module already did this. I want to check whether he did it and if not to throw an error.

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304234/check-if-a-given-middleware-is-being-used) may help you then.

Comment: Close but no cigar. I have seen this. I have come to believe that what I want is simply not possible.